# Read local .json from local .js without repos

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, localhost

I'm trying to write a chrome-extension that closes tabs when they're loaded and their links contain specific keywords, which I've saved in a `.json` file. Because the `content.js` has no access on the browser peripherals, I had to use the `background.js` script to close the tab. So far the extension does all that except loading the data from the `.json`, which means that I had to write the `json` (just for testing) into the `background.js`. Because I want to ban a lot of links this is'nt an option for me. So I decided on storing a list with the links in a `.json` file, which is stored in the same folder as the `background.js`, which means that it's on the localhost and not on any kink of webserver. That means that it should be possible to access this file, because after my research, I came to the assumption that the `background.js` runs on the localhost as well. So there should'nt occur any file accessing limitation issues right?

Unfortuantely I've got no idea how to write this in pure `.js`, because all the tutorials or posts here are either accessing the file from or in a webserver or using some kind of fancy library. This should be possible without one right?

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, {
  url: [
    {urlPrefix: 'https://www.google.de/'},
    {urlPrefix: 'https://sghm.eu/iserv/login'},
  ]
});

function closeTab(e) {
  if (!e.frameId) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(e.tabId);
  }
}
```

this is how my code looks now, I want to have some kind of `loadData('data.json')` function that returns the `.jsons` content, so that I can delete  this whole `.json` data strucure within the js.

It should be possible to access the **javascript** object notation language via **javascript**.

Comment: If there is no requirement that you modify your file from inside your code you could specify it as a web accessible_resource: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I want to access the `.json´ file in my chrome extensions background.js script.

Comment: I see, that is something I was looking to do as well, the best I came up with is having .js file with variables (or maybe only a single one in your case) that is "included" in every content script as well as specified as a background. I have an enums.js that I use to store objects and a utils.js that includes functions that are used all over my extension. Here is what my manifest looks like: https://github.com/gergelyszabo94/csgo-trader-extension/blob/master/extension/chrome/manifest.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think you can do this far easier and faster with using [Chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).  The data is saved as a json object and easy to reference and it sounds like exactly what you need as you're just referencing key/pair values anyway.